# Zend Framework 2 - Importer for multiple Rest or Soap Apis

Tags: api, rest, zend-framework2, doctrine, client

I want my ZF2 Application to import data from many different REST or SOAP Services, which may use different authentication types and so on.

Now I'm basically looking for a structure / architecture how to implement this, maybe some design patterns or ready to use modules if they exist.

Every information could help. I'm also thankful for API docs or tutorials that you provide.

But my main question is: How should be the structure for this kind of "importer"

My Application:

- Based on Zend Skeleton Application
- Using Doctrine 2
- Trying to use all ZF2 Best Practices I can find
- Consists of many modules, entities and complex associations in some cases
- Entities that I want to import are already working (crud operations, validation, ...)

Apis that I want to use:

- Usually E-Commerce stuff, like products, orders, stock keeping
- Magento Api (Thinking of Rest)
- Shopware and other important Webshops
- Ebay Stores
- Amazon (I think is going to be the hardest one)

Must have functionality:

- I want the api URLs and authentication data to be configurable in my app with doctrine entities
- The "Api" Entity should be associated to my "Shop" Entity. Orders or Products that I import or create directly in my App are also associated to my Shop entities. So every Shop/Ebay-Store/Amazon-Store is a "Shop" in my Application. This is already the part I've done.
- For example product import should be done directly from my app frontend, I'm thinking of retrieving the api data first and then import them incremtally / step for step
- I don't want fat controllers that transform the data into doctrine entities and save them one by one. This way complex associations would become very hard to maintain.
- Need a good approach for data transformation and hydration to doctrine entities. Because the data I retrieve from api will usually not have the same structure as my entities. Maybe an attribute that's a property of the "Product" entity in foreign app is excluded into an associated entity in my own application.
- Many modules in my application will have entities that should be importable from these apis, so I need a central component that does the job

How would be the best approach for this? I'm not asking for a complete solution, but ideas that fit these requirements.

Answer (score 0):

The Zend HTTP client and its relatives (like Zend OAuth) provides most of the functionality that you need to implement fetching the data from the services.

You can then persist the response in any number of ways, but a schema-less database like Mongo DB makes saving dynamic data much easier. If you are stuck using a relational DB like MySQL then you can either setup an EAV database, or use dynamically generated tables.